# How to set Default cursor in EditText Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

This is my layout file 
in this file the cursor set automatically in second Edit Text .  i need to change the first Edit Text . and why it happens . how to fix it?[image]

```
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/location"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:ems="10" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
      android:text="@string/country"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
      android:text="@string/temperature"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
      android:text="@string/humidity"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
      android:text="@string/pressure"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
      android:ems="10" >

      <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
      android:ems="10" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
      android:ems="10" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
      android:ems="10" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
      android:onClick="open"
      android:text="@string/weather" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i have attached image also for better understanding

Comment: Can you see the cursor in my layout ? i have marked it ! , that should be in Edittext of `location`. but by the default it sets in  Edittext of `location`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove request focus in Edittext2, then set to EditText1

```
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
  android:ems="10" >
 </EditText>

 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:ems="10" >

  <requestFocus />
 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you can write the code for it.

```
editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText1.requestFocus();
```